# Detecting (image) files that cannot be accessed with PowersShell

Tags: powershell

I'm facing a strange issue on a server whereby sometimes an image file will become corrupted in some way or another, that leads to nobody (including administrators) to be able to access it for a while, until the issue seemingly resolves itself somehow.

The effect from the administrators perspective is that they are told "access to X is denied" when trying to open it. Additionally there is no access to edit the file's permissions. All very strange.

What I'm looking to achieve with PowerShell, if possible, is a script that could iterate through the (thousands) of images in the directory, and somehow detect whether an image is in that inaccessible state. Because of the volume of files to iterate through, it would need to be pretty efficient.

Just looking for general direction pointers here. Given we're dealing with a file not even an admin can access, Would you say this is an job for **Get-Content**, or is there a better way in your experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Get-Content` which will generate an Permission Denied error if you don't have the permission to read and store the error in a separate variable.

```
Get-Content -Path $filePath -Encoding byte -TotalCount 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable $errorReadFile | Out-Null
```

This would only read the first character of the file `$filePath`. But it won't be displayed because of `Out-Null`. If an error occurs, it won't appear on the screen because of `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. And it will be stored into `$errorReadFile`.

So, then you can only keep Permission Denied type errors:

```
$errorReadFile = $errorReadFile | Where-Object { $_.CategoryInfo.Category -eq 'PermissionDenied' }
```

Then you display the files like this:

```
$errorReadFile.CategoryInfo.TargetName
```

Or, you can use `Get-NTFSEffectiveAccess` from the NTFSSecurity module : https://github.com/raandree/NTFSSecurity
It will tell you what permission you have on any item. But you might need an admin access to use it properly

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the advice from **Kluk**, I came up with the below which is working nicely via a scheduled task.

```
try {    
    $filePath = "\\LAN_PC\E\blah\blah"
                             
            $files = Get-Childitem -LiteralPath $filepath -file -Recurse 
    
                foreach ($f in $files){
                    Get-Content -LiteralPath $f.FullName -Encoding byte -TotalCount 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable +errorReadFile | Out-Null                
               }

            Write-host $errorReadFile -ForegroundColor Red
    
            if ($errorReadFile.CategoryInfo.TargetName.Count -gt 0) {    
                # Then we have a problem so do something                                            
            }
    }
    
    catch { 
        # Some code to alert me if there was an error   
    }
    
EXIT
```